# Is it possible to customize notepad++ to show icons in menu and submenu items?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ shows no icons in menus/submenus. Is there any possibility to customize it to show icons in the menus/submenus?

There is a Plugin which allows to customize the toolbar and use own buttons. Therefore I assume that there should also be possible to customize the menus. This would really improve the user experience using notepad++.

See image as example what I'm asking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Customizing menu images would be possible if someone writes a plugin for that.

- I have mediocre overview of available N++ plugin but there is currently no plugin for this. Searching did not help, too.
- I have checked N++ source code and confirm that icons are currently used only for toolbar, dialogs etc., not for menu.
- Adding icons to menu using configuration is not implemented.
- Adding icons to menu shouldn't be that difficult for plugin writer, menu uses standard Windows menu mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (year 2023) there is a plugin that
"Adds icons to the main menu, tab menu, context menu, and the tabs themselves."
Author: Franco Stellari
Homepage: https://github.com/francostellari/NppPlugins

You can easily find download and install it by using N++ Plugin Admin.